# Stata table: how to compute difference column without adding a new variable?

Tags: stata

In a panel data set, I'm using

```
table Region TIME if TIME==2014 | TIME==2020 | TIME==2030 | TIME==2040, contents(sum BF ) row
```

to create the following table:

```
------------------------------------------
          |              TIME             
Region    |   2014    2020    2030    2040
----------+-------------------------------
      701 |  26751   27941   29944   31477
      702 |  10456   11354   12723   13788
      704 |  41550   44481   49340   53273
      706 |  44976   47535   51940   55573
      709 |  43258   44398   46612   48191
      711 |   6580    7011    7539    7856
      713 |   9036   10139   11776   13194
      714 |   3091    3284    3563    3750
      716 |   9144    9730   10724   11543
      719 |   5719    6292    7258    8036
      720 |  11509   12161   13188   13919
      722 |  21403   22344   23839   25006
      723 |   4927    5094    5345    5447
      728 |   2460    2576    2761    2906
          | 
    Total | 240860  254340  276552  293959
------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to add a fifth column, which displays the difference between the year 2014 and 2040 in %.

Question: is this possible WITHOUT adding a new variable to the dataset? For instance by letting the fifth column being derived from a formula?

If not, how do I easily compute a new variable, taking account of the long format of the panel data set?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible within `table`.

Your variable could be something like

```
egen total2014 = total(BF / (TIME == 2014)), by(Region) 
egen total2040 = total(BF / (TIME == 2040)), by(Region) 
gen pcdiff = 100 * (total2040 - total2014)/total2014
```

after which you can tabulate its (mean) value for each region. See Section 10 in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055 for the first trick here.

You may need to go outside `table` for the tabulation, but if all else fails, `collapse` to a new dataset of totals and means.